# Efficient development workflow with Nuget?

Tags: .net, nuget

Nuget is a great tool but it seems to complicate the common process of iteratively modifying libraries and the hosting application at the same time.

For example, in the application if we have the app itself and 5 Nuget packages and we want to start changing three of the Nuget packages.  There seems to be limited efficient options.

Scenario 1:
Load up 4 copies of Visual Studio (one for the app and one for each of the packages), modify the packages, wait for packages to be built, update, modify host, build, rinse and repeat.

Scenario 2:
In the main app, rip out Nuget dependencies and add in proj files and iterate efficiently.  However, then once you are happy with the packages, the solution/proj files need to be repaired (Nuget restored, etc).

What are we missing here?  In the open source world, this is a snap.

Comment: This is hard to answer succinctly. Can you explain what problem are you trying to solve with NuGet?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "start changing three of the Nuget packages"? You haven't really described what you're doing terribly clearly. If you've got a single solution which is the source for 4 NuGet packages and an application using them, I would just use project references rather than Nuget references - and that shouldn't require any "repair" for anything...

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that NuGet qualifies as being "open source": https://nuget.codeplex.com/. I'm not sure I understand the relevancy though.

Comment: It is fairly straight forward so forgive me for not being clear.  We have libraries we want to use across the company, hence, internal use of Nuget.  However, we also don't want to go through a Nuget publish cycle just to test our app.  We want the convenience of a single solution but the power of Nuget.  Obviously if Nuget pacakges are reference in our app solution then we can't also have easy iteration on the libraries managed by Nuget.  This is obviously the standard workflow but I can find no answers of convenient library changes without massive publication cycles.

Comment: @halt00 have you find an answer for your question? I'm looking for same but can not get into it, in my case I wish core dev to have solution with projects, and front end dev have only web site with nuget packages

Answer (score 2):

NuGet is a good tool for versioning libraries which can be developed, tested and released as isolated packages. If you can treat them as a product, with feature requests, bug-fixes and a work-plan, then NuGet will support the release of new versions for systems to consume.

If your libraries are coupled to systems, such that features are added to the libraries to directly support the new features of a specific system, then you may want to make the library part of that system's release and development process. You can write the library with the system in mind, test it as part of the system, then release it via NuGet as part of the system deployment process. In development, the libraries are just project references and are immediately updated.

Essentially, you must either treat it a component of the system or as an isolated product; it would be a mistake to try and treat it as both.